# Retrieve Vendor name from Rest API on Add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, dokan

We are using Woocommerce and we are  trying to retrieve the vendor name for a product that has been added to a cart.
We are using the Cocart plugin to make the RestAPI work.
Our marketplace plugin is Dokan.

That is our code:

```
$cart_contents[ $item_key ]['product_author'] = apply_filters( 'cocart_product_author', $_product->getAuthor(), $_product, $cart_item, $item_key );
```

We got the below error

```
<b>Fatalerror</b>: UncaughtError: CalltoundefinedmethodWC_Product_Simple: : getAuthor()
```

My entire code

```
     * Return cart contents.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @since   2.0.0
     * @version 3.5.0
     * @param   array  $data
     * @param   array  $cart_contents
     * @param   string $cart_item_key
     * @param   bool   $from_session
     * @return  array  $cart_contents
     */
    public function return_cart_contents( $data = array(), $cart_contents = array(), $cart_item_key = '', $from_session = false ) {
        if ( CoCart_Count_Items_Controller::get_cart_contents_count( array( 'return' => 'numeric' ), $cart_contents ) <= 0 || empty( $cart_contents ) ) {
            /**
             * Filter response for empty cart.
             *
             * @since 2.0.8
             */
            $empty_cart = apply_filters( 'cocart_return_empty_cart', array() );

            return $empty_cart;
        }

        $show_thumb = ! empty( $data['thumb'] ) ? $data['thumb'] : false;

        // Find the cart item key in the existing cart.
        if ( ! empty( $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $cart_item_key = $this->find_product_in_cart( $cart_item_key );

            return $cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ];
        }

        foreach ( $cart_contents as $item_key => $cart_item ) {
            // If product data is missing then get product data and apply.
            if ( ! isset( $cart_item['data'] ) ) {
                $cart_item['data']                  = wc_get_product( $cart_item['variation_id'] ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'] );
                $cart_contents[ $item_key ]['data'] = $cart_item['data'];
            }

            $_product = apply_filters( 'cocart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $item_key );

            // If product is no longer purchasable then don't return it and notify customer.
            if ( ! $_product->is_purchasable() ) {
                /* translators: %s: product name */
                $message = sprintf( __( '%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce' ), $_product->get_name() );

                /**
                 * Filter message about item removed from the cart.
                 *
                 * @since 2.1.0
                 * @param string     $message Message.
                 * @param WC_Product $_product Product data.
                 */
                $message = apply_filters( 'cocart_cart_item_removed_message', $message, $_product );

                WC()->cart->set_quantity( $item_key, 0 ); // Sets item quantity to zero so it's removed from the cart.

                wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
            } else {
                // Adds the product name and title as new variables.
                $cart_contents[ $item_key ]['product_name']  = apply_filters( 'cocart_product_name', $_product->get_name(), $_product, $cart_item, $item_key );
                $cart_contents[ $item_key ]['product_title'] = apply_filters( 'cocart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product, $cart_item, $item_key );
                $cart_contents[ $item_key ]['product_author'] = apply_filters( 'cocart_product_author', $_product->getAuthor(), $_product, $cart_item, $item_key );
```

Comment: **Question:** Do you have a self-made method `get_post_author()` ?

Comment: No I don't have a self-made method get_post_author()

Comment: We did update the code, please check